# Data of saving file

Tags: javascript

In html file I need to display when that file was saved (time and date)

How can i do it? JavaScript?

```
<script>
var d = new Date(0);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
```

I need to know the the date when it has last been saved at the file system! And how can i change this 11-9-2014 at 23:7:55 to smth normal September 11 at 23:07?

Comment: No 0 in the Date. just use var d = new Date();

Comment: You mean, the date when it has last been saved at the file system?

Comment: Chris, yes, i need this one! and how can i change this 11-9-2014 at 23:7:55 to smth normal September 11 at 23:07?

Answer (score 0):

`document.lastModified` will give you the time the document was last modified so far as the browser is able to determine it. You won't find anything closer unless you implement some method to embed the time stamp into the file when you save it.

Comment: Some doc about Quentin's answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.lastModified

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.lastModified;
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/donal/w58v89Lh/